# Unable to insert 2d array within gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, beautifulsoup, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm trying to insert a 2D array in order to get two columns inserted into a sheet via gspread. I'm able to insert the individual lists fine, but inserting the array causes an error. Here's my code.

```
def megaDepotScrape():
listings = 0
priceList = []
skuList = []
# Iterate through the listings on the page, printing the price per entry
for listings in range(0, 12):
    # Connect to the site to be scraped
    siteURL = "https://megadepot.com/catalog/lab-equipment/multiwell-plates/brand:brandtech/"
    response = requests.get(siteURL, headers=headers)   
    # with open('brandtech.html', 'wb') as fp:
    #     fp.write(response.content)
    # Cook the soup
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
 
    # Find all containers with the appropriate class name
    # The 'strong' class 'hot' contains the price information
    price_containers = html_soup.find_all("strong", class_="hot")
    price = price_containers[listings]
    priceStr = list(price)
    priceList.append(priceStr)

    # Find all containers for the appropriate class name
    # The 'div' class 'product-wrapper' contains the SKU 
    sku_containers = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product-wrapper")
    sku = sku_containers[listings]
    # The sku is stored in the 'data-variant' of the 'article' tag
    for data in sku.find_all("article"):
        skuData = data["data-variant"]
        skuList.append(skuData)

    # Iterate through the loop 
    listings += 1
    # Write both lists to the sheets document
    # Reference update() in docs
rows = [priceList, skuList]    
print(rows)
#sheet.update('A1', [list(e) for e in zip(*rows)])
sheet.insert_row(skuList)
```

Here's the value of rows

`[[['$81.57'], ['$80.91'], ['$91.63'], ['$91.63'], ['$455.20'], ['$196.90'], ['$282.60'], ['$146.10'], ['$97.22'], ['$166.70'], ['$287.30'], ['$237.50']], ['781411', '781415', '781412', '781416', '701355', '701330', '701346', '701352', '782153', '701354', '781347', '781345']]`

And here's the error I get

````
    sheet.update('A1', [list(e) for e in zip(*rows)])      
  File "C:\Users\Jacob\PythonTestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 592, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jacob\PythonTestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1127, in update
    {'values': values, 'majorDimension': kwargs['major_dimension']}
  File "C:\Users\Jacob\PythonTestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 236, in values_update        
    r = self.client.request('put', url, params=params, json=body)
  File "C:\Users\Jacob\PythonTestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 76, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid values[0][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "$81.57"\n  }\n}\n', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}```

I'm not sure if there's some kind of limit that I'm hitting from uploading so much, or if there's some kind of error. Please let me know. Thank you.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From the following sample value.

  > Here's the value of rows

  > `[[['$81.57'], ['$80.91'], ['$91.63'], ['$91.63'], ['$455.20'], ['$196.90'], ['$282.60'], ['$146.10'], ['$97.22'], ['$166.70'], ['$287.30'], ['$237.50']], ['781411', '781415', '781412', '781416', '701355', '701330', '701346', '701352', '782153', '701354', '781347', '781345']]`
- I understood that the values of `priceList` and `skuList` might be the following values.

  ```
    priceList = [['$81.57'], ['$80.91'], ['$91.63'], ['$91.63'], ['$455.20'], ['$196.90'], ['$282.60'], ['$146.10'], ['$97.22'], ['$166.70'], ['$287.30'], ['$237.50']]
    skuList = ['781411', '781415', '781412', '781416', '701355', '701330', '701346', '701352', '782153', '701354', '781347', '781345']
  ```
- You want to put the values of `priceList` and `skuList` to 2 columns.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the array is required to be as follows.

  ```
    [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"],,,]
  ```
- When you want to insert the several rows with 2 columns, you can use `insert_rows()`.

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name you want to put the values.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)

# These values are from your question.
priceList = [['$81.57'], ['$80.91'], ['$91.63'], ['$91.63'], ['$455.20'], ['$196.90'], ['$282.60'], ['$146.10'], ['$97.22'], ['$166.70'], ['$287.30'], ['$237.50']]
skuList = ['781411', '781415', '781412', '781416', '701355', '701330', '701346', '701352', '782153', '701354', '781347', '781345']

# I modified below script.
row = [[e1[0], e2] for e1, e2 in zip(priceList, skuList)]
print(row) # You can confirm the value of "row".
sheet.insert_rows(row)
```

- When you run this script, the values of `priceList` and `skuList` are put to the columns "A" and "B" of "Sheet1".

#### References:

- [insert_rows(values, row=1, value_input_option='RAW')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert_rows#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_rows)

Answer (score 0):

Why tf you use insert_row as insert_cols ??? :D

If you want to insert values into one row just do

```
wks.insert_row(priceList, index=10, value_input_option='RAW')
```

If you want to insert values into one column just do

```
wks.insert_cols(values=[priceList], col=2, value_input_option='RAW')
```

Note that

```
priceList=['781411', '781415', '781412', '781416']
```

is like

```
priceList=['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4']
```

and

```
priceList=[['781411'], ['781415'], ['781412'], ['781416']]
```

is like

```
priceList=[['col1'], ['col2'], ['col3'], ['col4']]
```